# cant use javascript code with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xhtml

I have used the script at:

[http://www.javascript-coder.com/](http://www.javascript-coder.com/html-form/javascript-form-validation.phtml)

i use the following jquery code in which i am calling its methods.

```
$("form[name='registeruser'] input[name='register']").live('click',function(){
        //validateregister($("form[name='registeruser']"));
        var frmvalidator  = new Validator("registeruser");
        frmvalidator.addValidation("name","req");
});
```

my form "registeruser" is loading in a popup. When i click register button, nothing happens for the text field "name".

Help me with this

Comment: You're using jQuery to get "The name of form with the name 'registeruser'"?! Seriously? (As if using the name attribute on a form element wasn't bad enough in the first place).

Comment: ok making it simple for you i have changed the call for method Validator. but still its not giving me any result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok problem was that i was using a simple button to submit the form. which is not allowed in this script. I have to change the button to a submit button.

and i you really want to use a simple button instead of submit button, then following code can be used

in your form

```
<input type="button" value="submit" name="register" />
```

in your jquery

```
$("#registeruser input[name='register']").live('click',function(){
 //check if form 'registeruser' is valid or not
        if($("#registeruser").valid())
        {
            alert("ok");
        }
        else
        {
            jQuery.validator.messages.required = "";

            $("#registeruser").validate({
              errorClass: "requiredfields",
              highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
                 $(element).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
              },
              unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
                 $(element).removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
              },
              errorPlacement: function(error,element) {}

             });    
        }
```